# Restoring the state of the activity

Tags: android, screen-orientation

For restoring the state of the activity after it is recreated (for instance after the screen-orientation change) I implemented onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState(). It is simple to save/restore simple information like int, double etc. But what about saving/restoring objects like Timer?

Comment: Use SharedPreferences.

Comment: what you need to do is save the timer value and cacel the timer. when orientation changes the activity is destroyed and recreated. So cancel the timer and start the timer with the value saved

Comment: @Brontok sharedprefereces is for primitives so how can you use the same to save and restore objects like timer? and it is used to persist values across user sessions.

Comment: @Raghunandan i mean to save count of time in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot store "live" objects (like db connections) in the Activity arguments or saved instance data. Those mechanisms are designed so that the application can be completely stopped, so it only works with things that can be "serialized" and later restored.

What you can do is use fragments. If you add a fragment without UI (check [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html), look for 
“Adding a fragment without a UI”) and call on it [setRetainInstance(true)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance%28boolean%29) the fragment will get reattached to the activity, surviving any configuration change.

Hope it helps. (Remember you can use fragments with old Android versions by using the support package)